# Django clean method throwing KeyError on POST

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm getting a KeyError for 'password' when I try to submit my form.

trace:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/register/
Django Version: 1.2.1
Python Version: 2.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'djangoproject1.authentication']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\jec23\My Java Projects\djangoproject1\src\djangoproject1\authentication\views.py" in register
  20.         if rf.is_valid() and pf.is_valid():
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  121.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in _get_errors
  112.             self.full_clean()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  268.         self._clean_form()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in _clean_form
  296.             self.cleaned_data = self.clean()
File "C:\Users\jec23\My Java Projects\djangoproject1\src\djangoproject1\authentication\forms.py" in clean
  16.         if self.cleaned_data['cpassword']!=self.cleaned_data['password']:

Exception Type: KeyError at /register/
Exception Value: 'password'
```

views:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rf = forms.RegisterForm(request.POST)
        pf = forms.ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if rf.is_valid() and pf.is_valid():
            newuser = User(username=rf.cleaned_data['username'],email=rf.cleaned_data['email'])
            newuser.set_password(rf.cleaned_data['password'])
            newuser.save()
            profile = pf.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = newuser
            profile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/register-success/")
        else:
            return render_to_response("authentication/index.html", {'form1': rf, 'form2':pf})
    else:
        return main(request)
```

forms:

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(min_length=6,max_length=15)
    password = forms.CharField(min_length=6,max_length=15,widget = forms.PasswordInput())
    cpassword = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password',widget = forms.PasswordInput())
    email = forms.EmailField(label='E-mail Address')

    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['cpassword']!=self.cleaned_data['password']:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return self.cleaned_data

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phonenumber = forms.CharField(label='Phone Number')

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('user')
```

Comment: can you post the code that is using this form?

Comment: Can you post the template code as well?

Comment: @JPC: Is this the error message you are getting for `username` field? `Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters`

Comment: yes, thats the validation error message that I get when I don't try to override the username field

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Aha! The validation error message that you are seeing is actually not a validation error message. Let me explain. When you render the model form instance using `as_p`, it renders each field in the following way:

```
<p><label ...>fieldname</label> <input ... name="fieldname" /> HELP TEXT IF ANY</p>
```

The string `Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters` that you are seeing to the right hand side of the field is nothing but the help text. This help text is taken from the model definition - you can verify this by visiting `django/contrib/auth/models.py` and inspecting the definition of `User` class.

When you override the `username` field you are omitting any help text. Naturally the "error" disappears.

In order to verify this theory do the following in your `main` method.

```
def main(request):
    uf = forms.UserForm()
    upf = forms.UserProfileForm()
    print "User form is bound:%s errors:%s" % (uf.is_bound, uf.errors)
    return render_to_response("authentication/index.html", {'form1': uf, 'form2':upf})
```

**Update**

```
if self.cleaned_data['cpassword']!=self.cleaned_data['password']:
```

This line can cause trouble when the user doesn't supply one or both of `password` and `cpassword`. For example, try this from the Django shell:

```
>>> data = dict(username = 'admin', cpassword = 'foo', email='admin@bar.com')
>>> f = RegisterForm(data)
>>> f.is_bound
True
>>> f.is_valid()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 8, in clean
    if self.cleaned_data['cpassword']!=self.cleaned_data['password']:
KeyError: 'password'
```

Change your form's `clean` method to make sure that both values are present before comparing. Something like this:

```
def clean(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password', None)
    cpassword = self.cleaned_data.get('cpassword', None)
    if password and cpassword and (password == cpassword):
        return self.cleaned_data
    else:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
```

Comment: Ah!  That makes a ton of sense.  I would have never figured that out.  I got kinda annoyed with the ModelForm for user because I had to redefine fields and I was still getting that KeyError for some reason.  I ended up using a regular form and just creating the User.

Comment: Is it possible to make the helptext go away without overriding?

Comment: @JPC: You can override the `__init__` method of the form and set `self.fields['username'].help_text = None`. A bit crufty IMHO. Alternately you can use another method to display the form where you ignore the help text.

Comment: What about the KeyError?  I'll paste the stacktrace

Comment: @JPC: Updated answer. See above.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, however, from messing around with print statements, even when I put something in both textfields, the "password" field doesn't have a key.

Comment: What's the difference between calling .get on cleaned_data and just subscripting it?  I tried it your way and it worked, but if I use subscripts it still gives a key error, even if I do put values in for both fields

Comment: @JPC: Subscripting raises `KeyError` if the key is not found. `get` returns `None` or the optional second argument (which is also `None` in this case) if the key is not found. You can verify this with any dictionary object.

Comment: Still not quite working.  If you have a clean(self) method, it can access anything in cleaned_data, but if you have a clean_something(self) method, it can only access something.  Is that correct?  That's the behavior that I'm seeing.  I can get it to work if I use clean but if I use clean_password, then cpassword is always None

Comment: If your validation logic requires _multiple fields_ then `clean` is the one you should be using rather than `clean_fieldname`. The value of `cpassword` will always be `None` inside `clean_password`. This is expected as `clean_cpassword` hasn't been called yet and hence there is no value for cpassword.

Answer (score 23):

From my own experience, I found that if you want to do some validation in multiple fields, even if they are marked as required=True, when you override the `clean()` method in your form, if the fields you want to validate are not filled when submitting it and you try to acess them as `cleaned_data["field_name"]` your code will explode with a `KeyError`. To avoid this, just access the field in cleaned_data through the `get()` dictionary method and check if is None, or pass a default value. As a corollary:

```
my_field = cleaned_data.get("field_name")  # This is safe and it will work! :)
my_field = cleaned_data["field_name"]  # This will crash when the field was not filled! :(
```

I hope this helps someone else, I lost a great amount of time because of this silly thing!

Comment: This should be the answer