# How can I solve this KeyError

Tags: django, django-forms, keyerror

[image]

How to solve this?? Is anything wrong there??
I'm new to Django...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this solution
[stack solution for key error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15413820/11168176)

Comment: Hey, what are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Good day!

Probably, there is an error in the template HTML with missing `user_email` field in the `<form>`.

```py
# form.py
from django import forms
from django.core import validators


class UserForm(forms.Form):
    user_email = forms.EmailField()
    user_vmail = forms.EmailField()

    def clean(self):
        all_data = super().clean()
        print(all_data)
        user_email = all_data["user_email"]
        user_vmail = all_data["user_vmail"]

        if user_email != user_vmail:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email does not match")
```

This gives be the following:

```
[26/Jan/2022 05:57:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3702
{'user_email': 'asd@asd.asd', 'user_vmail': 'asd@asd.asd'}
[26/Jan/2022 05:57:43] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[26/Jan/2022 05:57:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3702
```

The source code: https://github.com/almazkun/django_form

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
user_email = all_data.get('user_email')

user_vmail = all_data.get('user_vmail')
```

or this

```
user_email = self.all_data.get('user_email')

user_vmail = self.all_data.get('user_vmail')
```

1st or 2nd will definitely fix that key error

Comment: `all_data` is a local variable, it's not related to `self`

Answer (score 0):

For more information, I strongly recommend checking the documentation, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    user_email= cleaned_data.get("user_email")
    user_vmail = cleaned_data.get("user_vmail")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `square` brackets `[]` for `keys` it will throw `KeyError` if that `key` not exists in your `all_data`

```
class user_form(forms.Form):
    user_email = forms.EmailField()
    user_vmail = forms.EmailField()

    def clean(self):
        all_data = super().clean()
        user_email = all_data['user_email'] #<---- throws key error if 'user_email' not in all_data
        user_vmail = all_data['user_vmail'] #<---- throws key error if 'user_vmail' not in all_data

        if user_email != user_vmail:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email Doesn't match")
```

So to avoid `KeyError` check for `key` if exists in your `all_data` as

```
class user_form(forms.Form):
    user_email = forms.EmailField()
    user_vmail = forms.EmailField()

    def clean(self):
        all_data = super().clean()
        if not ('user_email' in all_data.keys() and 'user_vmail' in all_data.keys()):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please fill all fields.")
    
        user_email = all_data['user_email']
        user_vmail = all_data['user_vmail']

        if user_email != user_vmail:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email Doesn't match")
```

Or to avoid `KeyError` use `()` as

```
user_email = all_data('user_email')
user_vmail = all_data('user_vmail')
```